# Можно ли установить gcc без root прав?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

У меня есть сервер но нет root доступа и мне нужно установить компилятор gcc. Возможно ли это сделать?

Linux 4.4.9 Ubuntu amd64

Comment: А что пишет при попытке установить без sudo?

Comment: В теории можно скачать исходники и скомпилировать под обычным пользователем, но чтобы скомпилировать нужен, та-дам, gcc. Поэтому либо через sudo (нужно быть в группе wheel, sudo, либо иметь прямое разрешение в sudoers), либо никак.

Comment: А если скомпилировать gcc на другой машине и закинуть на сервер  бинарник?

Comment: потребуется очень много чего пересобирать и копировать. проще на другой машине собрать то, что вы собирались собрать на этой. и скопировать готовое.

Comment: А зачем вам на сервере понадобилось что-то собирать???

Comment: @Ljil, небось виртуальный хостинг :)

Comment: А там не выдают root прав? Просто я всегда арендовывал именно сервер, а не хостинг.

Comment: Если коротко, то да.

Comment: А вы вообще *sudo* пытались?